# How to compile sass in Ext JS 4.2.1

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

I have worked very nicely compiling sass on extjs 4.1. But now i have downloaded latest version of ExtJs 4.2.1, its folder structure its self is different. **Can any one tell me how to compile sass in extjs 4.2.1?** Great appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is actually very good documentation from Sencha on this here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/theming.  Look especially in the "Styling your application" section.

Essentially, your SASS should go in your `ROOT/sass` folder, under either `var` or `src`.  Within those folders, you should make a folder structure that matches the component that you are styling with SASS (e.g. for `MyApp.view.MyWindow`, create `ROOT/sass/src/view/MyWindow.scss`).  The `src` folder is generally for SASS mixins and includes, and CSS class definitions.  The `var` folder is generally for setting SASS variables.

Once you have saved all of your files, a simple `sencha app build` should generate the `MyApp-all.css` file under the resources folder of your build.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sencha app watch` to compile your sass automatically at any change